# Why Instant.parse() string with timezone behaviour in java8 is different than java 17

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, timezone-offset, java-17

The following code snippet

```
Instant.parse("2023-08-08T00:00:00+02:00")
```

compiles and executes as expected in java-17. But when executed with java-8, throws the following exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-08-01T00:00:00+02:00' could not be parsed at index 19

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.Instant.parse(Instant.java:395)
    ...
```

My question is why? Did something change in java.time api?

Please note, i do know a way to workaround this, the following code works in java-8

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-08-01T00:00:00+02:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).toInstant()
```

It produces the desired result. I am interested to know whether within java-time api implementation, behaviour has been changed?

Comment: Maybe it was explicit before, now it's implicit. There are also key differences between the API in JDK 1.8 and 17. One of them is—for instance—the time precision. In Java 17, time is in nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: By implicit you mean, in java-17, Instant.parse() Implicitly uses the ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME while parsing. In java-8, we had to explicitly specify what kind of formatter we would to use? And since the backward compatibility is not broken here, instead java.time api has been improved, so all is well.

Comment: I've never found much use with the newer _Java_ time classes, I believe they were made to compliment _Java EE_, thus _"API-breaking"_ adjustments are more common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug which was fixed in Java 12:

[JDK-8166138: DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT should handle offsets](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8166138)

Versions 8 to 11 will throw this exception, while versions from 12 onwards will accept a time zone offset.

As the documentation says, the `Instant.parse` method uses the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` parser. The latter has been changed between versions [11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) and [12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) (see links). In version 12, the following sentence was added to the description of the ISO_INSTANT parser:

> When parsing, the behaviour of DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendOffsetId() will be used to parse the offset, converting the instant to UTC as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I should start reading javadocs again :)